# How to calculate time distribution without subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table containing list of cars, time they spent driving at a certain speed per year, as well as total time spent driving the same year. What I'm looking for is calculate % of time spent driving in different speeds.

Data looks like this:

```sql
create table #stats (
    car varchar(30), yr INT, speed NUMERIC(5,1), hoursSpent INT, hoursInPeriod INT
    PRIMARY KEY(car, yr, speed)
)

INSERT INTO #stats (
    car, yr, speed, hoursSpent, hoursInPeriod
)
VALUES  ('Volvo', 2019, 50, 20, 300)
,   ('Volvo', 2019, 65, 13, 300)
,   ('Volvo', 2019, 70, 30, 300)

,   ('Volvo', 2020, 50, 10, 250)
,   ('Volvo', 2020, 65, 25, 250)
,   ('Volvo', 2020, 70, 40, 250)

,   ('Volvo', 2021, 50, 5, 100)
,   ('Volvo', 2021, 70, 10, 100)

,   ('Tesla', 2019, 50, 5, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2019, 65, 20, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2019, 70, 10, 100)

,   ('Tesla', 2020, 50, 10, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2020, 65, 20, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2020, 70, 13, 100)

,   ('Tesla', 2021, 50, 30, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2021, 65, 20, 100)
,   ('Tesla', 2021, 70, 50, 100)
```

The important point to consider is that SUM of hoursSpent will never be equal to hoursInPeriod, one can think of hoursSpent as time spent moving, and hoursInPeriod as total time car "existed".

It's pretty easy to calculate the time-% by doing following query:

```sql
SELECT  speed
, SUM(hoursSpent) * 1.0 / (SELECT SUM(hoursInPeriod) FROM (select distinct car, yr, hoursInPeriod FROM #stats s) x)
FROM    #stats ss
GROUP BY speed
```

Expected result:

| speed | distribution |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 0.084210526315 |
| 65 | 0.103157894736 |
| 70 | 0.161052631578 |

The problem is that I can't use the above query.

I'm accessing this data through very rudimentary API which only allows to specify: select columns (any complex expression or function calls or window functions are ok as long as they don't "SELECT FROM" some table), table name, where condition, group by and order by.
It doesn't allow derived tables, joins or correlated subqueries that selects from other tables.

My question is, is it possible to calculate the distributed time with only the above constructs. I'm either missing something very simple, or maybe it's very hard. Optionally, I want to be able to GROUP BY car / year as well.

A query I considered:

```sql
SELECT speed
    , SUM(hoursSpent) / (SELECT SUM(hoursInPeriod) * 1.0 / COUNT(*))
FROM #stats ss
GROUP BY speed
```

It looks pretty good, unfortunately, it doesn't return correct result, because the COUNT isn't evenly distributed.

Comment: Both queries above contain subqueries. Can you use "derived tables" e.g. `select * from (select a,b,c from t1) d` and: Can you use window functions such as `sum(col1) over(partition by car)`

Comment: I have updated the question a bit @PaulMaxwell, Window functions or other complex expressions are ok, SELECT is OK, unless you have FROM clause. Derived tables aren't allowed, only simple table names

Comment: I'm sorry the requirements are a bit stupid, but that's what i have to work with :(

Comment: I assume joins are OK? But you cannot generate a date series and join to that series as a derived table. Are you certain? How did the temp table get created?  and I don't follow *"SELECT is OK, unless you have FROM clause"*, query 1 in question has multiple selects & multiple froms.

Comment: Mention your expected result in table format which helps to understand your question.

Comment: Query 1 demostrates the actual result i'm looking for, but i can't use that query since it contains forbidden operators :D Temp table is just example of data, in reality it's a real table. Joins are not OK

Comment: Do you want it per car, or per year, or both? Your expected results doesn't have any of them.

Comment: I'm satisfied if i can get values per speed as in expected table. But it would be great if i could also generate values per speed, year or car.

Comment: @SomendraKanaujia, updated answer with expected result

Comment: Ideally, what i want is to have a SUM(DISTINCT hoursInPeriod Per Car), but this construct doesn't exist in SQL Server, and i can't emulate it

Comment: without the ability to use at least "derived table" and/or joins I think you are truly stuck without a solution, as pointed out in the comment immediately above

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions with  aggregation. Starting from your existing query:

```
SELECT speed,
    1.0 * SUM(hoursSpent)
        / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(hoursInPeriod)) OVER(), 0) as ratio
FROM #stats ss
GROUP BY speed
```

The window sum computes the grand total of hours spent, which we can use as a denominator to compute the ratio (with a safety against division-by-zero errors).

---

If you have repeated `hoursInPeriod` on each year, then we probably need another level of aggregation:

```
SELECT speed, 
    1.0 * SUM(hoursSpent)
        / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(hoursInPeriod)) OVER(), 0) as ratio
FROM (
    SELECT speed, hoursInPeriod, SUM(hoursSpent) hoursSpent
    FROM #stats
    GROUP BY speed, hoursInPeriod
) s
GROUP BY speed
```

Comment: For clarity for OP: Window functions *over* aggregation ie. the aggregation happens first, then the windowing

Comment: The problem is, i cannot summarize hoursSpent, since it is not total number of hours :(. I have to use hoursInPeriod as distributed. Otherwise it would be simple. To explain it, the hours spent only log when car is moving, but not when it stands still. The latter time is contained in hoursInPeriod

Comment: @siggemannen: ok, so `SUM(SUM(hoursInPeriod)) OVER()`?

Comment: That creates too much hoursInPeriod, since hoursInPeriod is the same for every speed / year combination. That's the thing with this query, it's maddeningly hard to solve!

Comment: @siggemannen: ok I see… I updated my answer - will your software support the subquery though?

Comment: the heart of this question is that subqueries aren't allowed (so it is stated in title and subsequent comment replies) but even your second query has too many hoursInPeriod

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of windowed functions!

Give this a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car, Speed, yr, SUM(.0+hoursSpent) OVER (PARTITION BY Car, yr, Speed ORDER BY Speed) AS HoursAtSpeed, MAX(.0+hoursInPeriod) OVER (PARTITION BY Car, Yr ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS TotalHours, 
SUM(.0+hoursSpent) OVER (PARTITION BY Car, yr, Speed ORDER BY Speed)/MAX(.0+hoursInPeriod) OVER (PARTITION BY yr ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM #stats
 ORDER BY Yr, Car, Speed
```

| Car | Speed | yr | HoursAtSpeed | TotalHours | PercentHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tesla | 50.0 | 2019 | 5.0 | 100.0 | 0.016666 |
| Tesla | 65.0 | 2019 | 20.0 | 100.0 | 0.066666 |
| Tesla | 70.0 | 2019 | 10.0 | 100.0 | 0.033333 |
| Volvo | 50.0 | 2019 | 20.0 | 300.0 | 0.066666 |
| Volvo | 65.0 | 2019 | 13.0 | 300.0 | 0.043333 |
| Volvo | 70.0 | 2019 | 30.0 | 300.0 | 0.100000 |
| Tesla | 50.0 | 2020 | 10.0 | 100.0 | 0.040000 |
| Tesla | 65.0 | 2020 | 20.0 | 100.0 | 0.080000 |
| Tesla | 70.0 | 2020 | 13.0 | 100.0 | 0.052000 |
| Volvo | 50.0 | 2020 | 10.0 | 250.0 | 0.040000 |
| Volvo | 65.0 | 2020 | 25.0 | 250.0 | 0.100000 |
| Volvo | 70.0 | 2020 | 40.0 | 250.0 | 0.160000 |
| Tesla | 50.0 | 2021 | 30.0 | 100.0 | 0.300000 |
| Tesla | 65.0 | 2021 | 20.0 | 100.0 | 0.200000 |
| Tesla | 70.0 | 2021 | 50.0 | 100.0 | 0.500000 |
| Volvo | 50.0 | 2021 | 5.0 | 100.0 | 0.050000 |
| Volvo | 70.0 | 2021 | 10.0 | 100.0 | 0.100000 |

You can adjust how the values are group by changing the columns included in the PARTITIION BY for each of the windowed functions. I have it broken down by car, speed and year in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the percentage for each row, per car per year, you just need to remove the aggregation and add a `PARTITION BY` with a window function:

```sql
SELECT
  s.car,
  s.yr,
  s.speed,
  s.hoursSpent * 1.0 / SUM(s.hoursSpent) OVER (PARTITION BY s.car, s.yr) 
FROM #stats s;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/_Yk0jQg7)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't just use hoursSpent, because it only contains driving hours, and not all hours which only exist in hoursInPeriod. I updated the question with a bit of clarification. Sorry about that

Comment: Seems your design is suspect: `hoursInPeriod` is a relation of Periods, not of CarYears, so should have been in a separate table

Comment: In reality the table is a view, i just simplified the messy details for this exercise

Answer (score 0):

Can you make two separate calls to the API?

Below is a pseudo sample based on Python to combine the results of 2 calls without subqueries (nb "api_call" is a placeholder for how you call your api):

Get the needed grand total of hoursInPeriod into a variable:

```
total_hours_in_period_query = "SELECT SUM(hoursInPeriod) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT car, yr, hoursInPeriod FROM #stats) AS subq"
total_hours_in_period = api_call(total_hours_in_period_query)
```

Then make a second call to get the sum of hours spent for each speed and divided by the result of the first call:

```
hours_spent_query = f"SELECT speed, SUM(hoursSpent) / {total_hours_in_period} FROM #stats GROUP BY speed"
results = api_call(hours_spent_query)
```